# Spring Integration: Inject request scoped twitter-template bean into inbound-channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration

I have an annotation configured request-scoped TwitterTemplate bean and I want to inject that bean into an xml configured inbound-channel-adapter.

What is the best way to do that and are there any implications that need to be considered in case of multiple sessions accessing the same inbound-channel-adapter?

Have you got any examples of twitter inbound-channel-adapter configured through java?

Answer (score 0):

Inject an ApplicationContext object into your xml configured bean, as a property.
Your xml configured bean can implement InitializingBean and override the afterPropertiesSet method, where you get an instance of your twitterBean as shown in the code below.

You context gets merged irrespective of the configuration mechanism you use.

```
YourXmlBean implements InitializingBean {

ApplicationContext ctx;
TwitterTemplate twitBean;

...

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet(){
 twitBean = (TwitterTemplate) ctx.getBean("twitterTemplate");
}
```